# does std::move in algorithm destroy overlapped object?

Tags: c++

**std::move** function in **algorithm** library

taken from *cppreference.com*

```
template< class InputIt, class OutputIt >
constexpr OutputIt move( InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first );
```

will overlapped element be destroyed if I move in same array

also, if I call **construct** 2 times like this (using **allocator_traits**):

```
alloc_trait::construct(alloc, p, 1);
alloc_trait::construct(alloc, p, 2);
```

will old element be destroyed ? or I have to manually destroy it ?

Destroy = call destructor not deallocate

Comment: what is an overlapped element? Please one question per question

Comment: To quote cppreference.com: "The behavior is undefined if d_first is within the range [first, last)."

Comment: So what should I do in this case ? How to make sure there's no memory leak.

Comment: Why do you think there could be a memory leak, and where? There must be some context that you're not mentioning.

Comment: Your second question can be answered by reading about what `construct` and "placement new" do.

Comment: Destructors need to explicitly called. Verify with debug trace or a breakpoint in the destructor.

Comment: In any case, the "algorithm move" will move-assign the elements, and that doesn't destroy anything. I think you may have misunderstood what "move" means in C++.